# Is the values in a capacity declared arrayList null?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

`String[] arr = new String[10];`
This creates an array with 10 elements all set to null. The first null element can be accessed with `arr[0]`

`ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>[10];`
This creates an array with capacity of 10 but apparently no elements. Is this why you cannot use `arr2.get(0)` which returns an error? Because there are no elements present?

Comment: _This creates an array_ It creates an `ArrayList`, no? _Is this why you cannot use arr2.get(0) which returns an error?_ Doesn't the error mention the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. An ArrayList is a class and an object to the class should be created using a constructor

   - `ArrayList<String>[10]` produces an `error: cannot create array with '<>'` error
   - Using constructor, the ArrayList is constructed as `ArrayList<String>(10)`;
2. It is to be noted that this statement creates an **Empty ArrayList** of *initial* size 10.
3. The ArrayList only gets populated when you `push` values into it.

   Refer the following for more understanding:
   [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) [[2]](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist/) [[3]](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist)